# environment file variable equals another variable

Tags: environment-variables

Is there a way to create an .env file that defines a variable with the value of another variable?

I have tried using:
`var1=$var2`

And it obviously doesn't work.

Any takes?

Comment: What software uses this `.env` file?

Comment: You can source them from the bash using `source .env` and all the variables defined there will be available as environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

What does "doesn't work" mean?

```
$ echo -n $var1
$ echo 'var1=$PATH' > whatever
$ cat whatever
var1=$PATH
$ source whatever
$ echo $var1
/sbin:/usr/sbin:...
$
```